# Unable to get ng2-dragula working in Plunker

Tags: javascript, angular, plunker, dragula, ng2-dragula

I have been trying to get `ng2-dragula` working in Plunker but it's not quite there.

Here is my `config.js`. Please ignore the untidy code for now. I have set the Angular and RxJs versions explicitly as the latest versions were not playing nice with each other.

```
var angularVersion;
if (window.AngularVersionForThisPlunker === 'latest'){
  angularVersion = ''; //picks up latest
}
else {
  angularVersion = '@' + '5.2.11';
}

System.config({
  //use typescript for compilation
  transpiler: 'typescript',
  //typescript compiler options
  typescriptOptions: {
    emitDecoratorMetadata: true
  },
  paths: {
    'npm:': 'https://unpkg.com/'
  },
  //map tells the System loader where to look for things
  map: {
    'app': './src',
    '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core'+ '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/core.umd.js',
    '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/common.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/http': 'npm:@angular/common' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/common-http.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler' + '@5.2.11'  + '/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
    '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/http.umd.js',
    '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router' + '@5.2.11' +'/bundles/router.umd.js',
    '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/forms.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations': 'npm:@angular/animations' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/animations': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/platform-browser-animations.umd.js',
    '@angular/animations/browser': 'npm:@angular/animations' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/animations-browser.umd.js',

    '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/core-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/testing': 'npm:@angular/common' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/common-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/common/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/common' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/common-http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/compiler/testing': 'npm:@angular/compiler' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/compiler-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/platform-browser-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/testing': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/http/testing': 'npm:@angular/http' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/http-testing.umd.js',
    '@angular/router/testing': 'npm:@angular/router' + '@5.2.11' + '/bundles/router-testing.umd.js',
    'tslib': 'npm:tslib@1.6.1',
    'rxjs': 'npm:rxjs@5.5.10/',
    'rxjs/operators': 'npm:rxjs@5.5.10/operators.js',
    'typescript': 'npm:typescript@2.2.1/lib/typescript.js',
    'dragula': 'npm:dragula',
    'ng2-dragula': 'npm:ng2-dragula',
    'contra': 'npm:contra',
    'crossvent': 'npm:crossvent',
    'atoa': 'npm:atoa',
    'ticky': 'npm:ticky',
    'custom-event': 'npm:custom-event'
  },
  //packages defines our app package
  packages: {
    app: {
      main: './main.ts',
      defaultExtension: 'ts'
    },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  }
```

I have also added some more packages from `contra` onward as it was throwing errors in the console, which I assumed are needed by `dragula`. The problem is that in [dragula.js](https://unpkg.com/dragula@3.7.2/dragula.js), it requires it's own [./classes](https://unpkg.com/dragula@3.7.2/classes.js).

Debugging it in Chrome Developer Tools reveals that the object is in fact this [classes package](https://unpkg.com/classes@0.3.0/classes.js). I'm not entirely sure where this is coming from, I assume it's a package required somewhere.

Is there a way around this?

[Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/mPV4JnN1KXwjFomanuVy/)

Comment: Is Plunker a necessary requirement for your needs ? Otherwise, you can also use Stackblitz, it will resolve automatically missing packages... Here is an example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-axa6sg You can also get some inspirations in Stackblitz dependency trees

Comment: No it isn't necessary. Stackblitz looks great. Thanks very much.